# Suggestions on instruments to detect pachyderms

Tags: sensor, wireless

I am doing a project to detect the pachyderms in the forests when they cross the borders. Now is there is any other way other than seismic or sound waves to detect the pachyderms before they cross a border (Ruling out the camera's). I would love your valuable inputs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they travel along roads or paths?

Comment: Two suggestions:  Infrared motion detectors like the ones used on automatic lights (tuned to only react to large, warm objects) or else a radar kind of thing - low level radio signal, and detect variations in the reflections.  There are commercially available microwave units that combine the transmitter and receiver and put out an AC signal proportional to the speed and size of the moving object.  Goint that route would require some kind of signal processing to differentiate between trees waving in the wind and elephants walking - maybe use multiple sensors and combine the processed results.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electrical or electronic engineering.

Comment: they often come outta forests and attack irrigation areas. So need a system to detect them and alert the farmers. @JRE nice idea.

Comment: They dislike lights at night. More so if they are turned on occasionally to suggest that people may be there.

Comment: Why do people think that this is NOT about e... engineering. As COTS Pachyderm_Proliferation_Preventers are probably as rare as hens teeth, designing is liable to be required.

Comment: Why ruling out cameras? A camera with IR illuminators for night-vision and some image recognition would seem like a relatively sensible approach to a fairly tricky problem. A Raspberry Pi + IR camera module + OpenCV library would get you a very cheap open platform to start with. I assume tagging the pachyderms somehow is not possible / acceptable?

Comment: @Andyaka What makes you think this is not an electronics design question or application. | Same question to people who upvoted Andy's comment. |Same question to people who downvoted the question. || What's with youse guys? What world do you live in that cannot create actual real world solutions with electronics?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon this can probably be solved with equipment readily available without needing to design something in electronics.

Comment: I agree with @RussellMcMahon, seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: Thanks people for trying to answer the question instead of just marking question as unrelated.

@JohnU That was initially my idea but camera's distance to detection is little low. But it is better than my friend's suggestion to use pressure pads.

My idea was to use seismic sensors to detect the elephants when they are within a certain range. (i.e.30mts) I need a cost effective solution with easy maintenance and free from environmental fiddling(monkeys and birds) :P. My friend suggested a drone with IR camera module.

Comment: Sounds like a good application for some drunk red necks with guns.

Comment: Last I checked cameras can see over 30m, the ones we work on can see ~200m in pitch black. That's full-HD 1080p with 30x zoom and IR illuminators.

Comment: How is this not an electronic design question? Does it have to be component level design to qualify? (and many accepted questions have solutions at the system or module level). Does the OP have to know the solution to be able to specify it as electronic based? Can you buy turnkey elephant detectors off the shelf? Many allowed questions come far closer to "plug bits together" than this one - eg "How big a solar panel do I need for xxx?". Are we averse to real world issues here?

Comment: Implementing those type of camera's are not cost effective and you need to put proper security measures to safe-guard it.@JohnU

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The question isn't necessarily a good fit because it's open-ended and it's also not clear if the OP is looking for an off-the-shelf solution (or is capable of implementing a "complicated" system). Ultimately it's a personal judgement call.

Comment: @W5VO I agree with "... isn't necessarily..." AND that is what I take issue with in cases such as this. In many similar cases we start with too little information, have a few learned gentlemen make necessarily  arbitrary (at best( judgement call) and then lock out a new user with almost always spurious "reasons" given.If left alone such questions usually die and the users move on to friendlier locales. If given a chance and a small amount of work such questions and users and questions can 'prove themselves'. I'd say that perhaps 1 week would be a reasonable time. As it is we do violence ....

Comment: .... to a significant number of new users for no reason which is obvious to me (or them) and while this MAY reduce the noise somewhat it also wipes out a number of people who would end up contributing usefully.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The problem is that nobody (you included) seems to want to take care of the issues with these questions.

Comment: @W5VO 1. There may BE NO issues with "these questions". 2. Labelling this one of "these questions" suggests it needed major changes to make it suitable. While it would benefit from (much) more detail it seems to be doing well enough as is. (3) I have no idea why you say either that nobody or I want to take care of the issues with "these questions". That sounds like fertile ground for a meta discussion. - What indentifies a question as need ing attention of the sort you have in mind? What sort of attention do they need? How do we hold off the knee capping squad long enough to get user dialog...

Comment: ... going to fix things. I answered this question as much to keep it accessible for dealing with as anything else initially. It was obvious [tm] that it had merit but that it was heading for knee capping very shortly. Once this happens it is exceeding hard to interact with the OP.
| I have talked to a number of people offlist about closed questions and what to do next. Some survive, some don't. Quite how you manage to be more willing to "deal with the issues" than I am I know not. Edification would be useful.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You make good points, but I feel like we are talking past each other to some extent. This (meaning the comments section of a question) is not a good venue for this discussion. Would you be interested in starting a meta.EE post? I probably won't have time to get to it until tomorrow.

Comment: As an aside, there are groups of researchers and environmentalists who are experimenting with bees hives as a deterrent for elephants.  Most of the experiments take place in Africa, but there is one in [Sri Lanka](http://elephantsandbees.com/sri-lanka/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an answer of my earlier comment:

Two suggestions:

1. Infrared motion detectors like the ones used on automatic lights (tuned to only react to large, warm objects)
2. Radar kind of thing - low level radio signal, and detect variations in the reflections. There are commercially available microwave units that combine the transmitter and receiver and put out an AC signal proportional to the speed and size of the moving object. Going that route would require some kind of signal processing to differentiate between trees waving in the wind and elephants walking - maybe use multiple sensors and combine the processed results.

---

Expanding since seismic and acoustic aren't really ruled out (see comments.)

3. Seismic detection:  A picket line of seismic detectors along the border that transmit their signals in real time to a central processor.  Using the differences in arrival time for strong signals, you could locate the pachyderms relative to the fence.  With enough processor power and enough sensors, you could follow the pachyderms in real time on a monitor.  More processing would let you extrapolate from movements to determine if they are headed towards the border.  This could be more long range than any of the other methods.  If the pickets are in a zig-zag instead of a straight line, you could even follow them on the other side of the border (where they go after crossing the border.)
4. Acoustic detection (microphones) as above.  Probably less long range and more prone to false signals than seismic.  Your processing would have to look for the sound of (pachyderm) footsteps rather than just signal strength as with seismic.

Given that one of your comments says you want an early warning system, I'd probably go for number 3 - zig zag line, and lots of processing.  If you want cheap, I'd go with the IR motion detectors along the border - just wire them to a panel of indicator lights where ever it is you are going to do the monitoring.

Comment: Elephants use infra-sonic to communicate. Do you think this can be utilised by multiple sensors? If so what kind of sensor could I use?

Comment: @AshwinAsp - I thought you had excluded sound waves in your OP.  You could use multiple sensors for infra-sonic (low frequency microphones) and process the output so as to locate the sources of certain sounds.  If the elephants don't "talk," though, you won't catch them.  I think you would do better to try to detect the animal rather than something it might not do.  Seismic would be a possibility, though, since they can't avoid walking if they are trying to cross the border.

Comment: I didn't mean to exclude it. It was meant to be like, to go out of the box. So if there are any ideas related to it, it's always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. But its not about recording sound of footsteps in acoustic detection. Elephants communicate through each other using infrasonic sounds which can travel upto 4kms! But the real problem lies when it is not communicating. But thanks for the info. It made me do a little bit of research on everything.

Answer (score 5):

As COTS Pachyderm-Proliferation-Preventers are probably as rare as hens teeth, designing is liable to be required. Electronic means seems liable to be a preferred one.

---

Beam breaking (IR or perhaps visible) at above typical average person or other-creature  height seem liable to offer good success of perceiving pending pachydermal plundering.

A single beam will remain broken for t = Lp/Vp
(for obvious meanings of L, V and P)
and you can decide how L a worst case small P is and what max V it moves at to give a likely estimate of the **minimum** time a beam is liable to be broken for, allowing discrimination against smaller and or faster moving beasties with smaller minimum L/V ratios. Positioning a few beams a short distance apart where separation is  say >= 2 x Lp_typical would give you some ability to count numbers in a group.

Triggering a light in the path of perambulating pachydermae may lead to aversive behaviour.

---

Doppler RADAR units (as once commonly used as door opener sensors) are liable to be successful with probabilistic predictions based on the ponderous pachydermal progress. As with beam breaking - size and speed of the target could be used to filter out signals from pussy-cats, possums and people

---

A simple and easy solution would be to find foodstuffs which are non perishable and attractive to proliferating pachyderms and mount it in such a manner that it was accessible to the target creatures but not readily disturbed otherwise. Add simple monitoring means and when the prey prises the food material from its location the trap is sprung.

Comment: +1 Funnier than mine, though basically the same ideas.

Comment: Grin, If the elephants have known pathways, I recall hearing about a ground pressure sensing system that had coax or optical fiber (?) buried in the ground.  And I think TDR of the cable could show when and where it was disturbed.  Would that be more robust than IR?  (I don't know.)

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your suggestions. I will look into it :)

Answer (score 2):

Bees appear to work - the hives buzz more when elephants get closer. Since elephants are scared of bees, this wouldn't be a neutral observation, but actually deter them from attacking the crops. See http://elephantsandbees.com/

If you want an higher maintenance technology which doesn't act as a deterrent and doesn't make honey, then you can use mesh networks and detect changes in the signal strength between the nodes. This can work for human sized targets, so should be able to use a larger mesh with larger beasts.

Comment: +1 An apparently OTW suggestion with a solid foundation, albeit not an electronic one :-). Electronic monitoring of hive buzziness to determine progress of a group of elephants across an area may be possible. While that's a half lighthearted suggestion it could be easily implemented for a capital cost of 10's of dollars per node at spacings of hundreds of meters.

Comment: I've heard that elephants and bees don't get along but thats a wonderful idea. Will definitely look into it :) Thank You